# Create a Collapsible Master-Detail View From Another Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm designing an Excel template for importing data (into another DBMS).
The problem is, the data will be separated (normalized) into several tables in my DBMS (master-detail model).

Let's say I have two sheet **Order** and **Order Detail**.

The **Order** contains: `ORDERID, CUSTOMERID, EMPLOYEEID, ORDERDATE, REQUIRED_DATE,` and `SHIPPED_DATE`.

While **Order Detail** contains: `ORDERID, PRODUCTID,` and `QUANTITY`

I'm planning to create a template like this:

[image]

When the Order is entered, there will be a collapsible pane to enter the Order Detail (from corresponded Order). Is it possible to create something like this? If so, how to achieve that?

Comment: I think yes. But you'll need to use a `UserForm` for the collapsible pane. You can use a `ListBox` which transfers/pulls data to/from your **Order Detail** Sheet. If your **Oder Detail** is a continues data record as well, then you can use a temporary sheet to dump data when updating or retrieving.

Comment: @L42: Is any alternative beside using UserForm? I think UserForm is inappropriate since it's showed as a pop up rather than collapsible pane itself. I already use grouping feature, but I don't know how to link the **Order** to **Order Detail**.